# Why mouse over function not work when use with javascript load content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Why mouse over function not work when use with javascript load content ?

mouse over function like this

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/peap/hyeg6qre/1/)

i want to use function mouse over in page : `test5.php` but not work , How can i do ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#love-trigger').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'love-trigger') $('#love-box').animate({
            top: '0px' , opacity: 1
    }, 100);   
        clearTimeout( $('#love-box').data('timer') );


                if (e.target.id == 'love-trigger') $('.notch').animate({
            top: '33px' , opacity: 1
    }, 100);   
        clearTimeout( $('.notch').data('timer') );


    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#love-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#love-box').animate({
            top: '10px' , opacity: 0
    }, 100);
            }, 1000)
        );


                $('.notch').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.notch').animate({
            top: '35px' , opacity: 0
    }, 100);
            }, 1000)
        );



    }
});

});//]]>  

</script>




<style type="text/css">
#love-box{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    top: 10px;
}
</style>




<div id="love-box" class="love-box_text">
    Star Star
    <b class="notch"></b>
</div>

        <img src="http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/stars/outlined_black_star_u272D_icon_256x256.png" id="love-trigger" style=" margin-left: 28px; height: 62px;"/>

<br>

this is fucntion on index.php (Show "Star Star" When mouse over)







<br><br><br><br><br>




<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var username = $("#username").val();
// you can check the validity of username and password here
$.post("test5.php",{username:username},        
function(data) {
   $('#results').html(data);
});
});
</script>
<div id="results" style=" width: 100%; ">
</div>

this is fucntion on test5.php (not work! How to do ?)
```

test5.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#love-trigger').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'love-trigger') $('#love-box').animate({
            top: '0px' , opacity: 1
    }, 100);   
        clearTimeout( $('#love-box').data('timer') );


                if (e.target.id == 'love-trigger') $('.notch').animate({
            top: '33px' , opacity: 1
    }, 100);   
        clearTimeout( $('.notch').data('timer') );


    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#love-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#love-box').animate({
            top: '10px' , opacity: 0
    }, 100);
            }, 1000)
        );


                $('.notch').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.notch').animate({
            top: '35px' , opacity: 0
    }, 100);
            }, 1000)
        );



    }
});

});//]]>  

</script>




<style type="text/css">
#love-box{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    top: 10px;
}
</style>




<div id="love-box" class="love-box_text">
    Star Star
    <b class="notch"></b>
</div>

        <img src="http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/stars/outlined_black_star_u272D_icon_256x256.png" id="love-trigger" style=" margin-left: 28px; height: 62px;"/>
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from test5.php... Are you?.. Also.. why are you passing an username if you're **not** getting and using it?

Comment: This is for exam my code  (in this exam not use post username ^^) .

Comment: It is pointless to do a POST request by sending nothing and pretend to receive something. If you just need to load the test5.php page, use $.load, not $.post . Check a basic tutorial about POST requests.

Comment: –  briosheje - when i use `$.load` i can not get data from `test5.php`

Comment: You don't have any PHP code in your test5.php . Moreover, since index.php is a PHP file, just use `include('test5.php');` instead of the $.post.

Comment: –  briosheje , in my code , i must to use java post to `test5.php`, cannot use `include`

Comment: Fine, then check a basic tutorial on how to use $.post and how to use PHP, because you're doing it wrong. It has no sense to include that using $.post anyway, and whoever told you to do such should know that.